# Are any New Guinea snakes invasive?

Tags: geography, geobiology

Papua New Guinea has many species of snakes, some of which are dangerous:

https://www.ecologyasia.com/verts/png-snakes.htm

Are any of these species invasive, or are they all indigenous?

Or, since that may be a blurry line, let me phrase it more precisely: did any of the snake species of the island, arrive since 1800?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. None of the species we currently consider invasive on Papua New Guinea are reptiles.

A web site [here](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search?dataset_key=a38c7d49-5a5d-4aa6-a64e-421178bd06d7) has a [dataset which lists 51 invasive species](https://www.gbif.org/dataset/a38c7d49-5a5d-4aa6-a64e-421178bd06d7) for that location. Of the 3 species in the phylum [chordata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordate), 2 are mammals and 1 is a bird. (This is the taxonomic breakdown)

- Plantae 22
- Animalia 19
- Arthropoda 14
- Chordata 3
- ```
   Mammalia 2
  ```
- ```
   Aves 1
  ```
- Nematoda 1
- Unknown phylum 1
- Bacteria 4
- incertae sedis 3
- Fungi 2
- Chromista 1

No reptiles, so no snakes are considered invasive species.